# How to list documents with duplicate values in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregate

I'm new to mongodb, and I have documents like this

```json
{
  "id_order": "same_value",
  "name_wa": "diah"
},
{
  "id_order": "same_value",
  "name_wa": "andy"
}
```

I want to list the all "name" values which has same "id_order" values. So I tried :

```js
db.order.aggregate([
  {"$group" : { "_id": "$id_order", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
  {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
  {"$sort": {"count" : -1} }
]);
```

Result :

```json
{
  "id_order": "same_value",
  "count": 2
}
```

What I wanted :

```json
{
  "id_order": "same_value",
  "count": 2,
  "name_values": [
    "andy",
    "diah"
  ]
}
```

It should be easy, what I'm missing ?

Comment: just add this `name_values: { $push: "$name_wa" }` in your $group stage, and project stage as well to appear this field in result

Comment: just tried it, updated my question, it returns empty array. @turivishal

Comment: It is working perfectly you can check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bQ1PU3dK4FY)

Comment: **Unrelated**: you're making `$project` more complicated than it is. If you don't want to rename a field just use `field:1`. Examples: `count:1, name_values:1`. Don't know why the downvote though. The post is ok.

Comment: @turivishal yes, it worked. my mistake. many2 thanks.

Comment: @Minsky many thanks, I thought $project command was obligatory.

Comment: @HendryH. it is . check the usage, you'll get it quick.

Answer (score 0):

Use $push operator.

```html
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$group": {"_id": "$id_order", "count": {"$sum": 1 }, "name_values": {"$push": "$name_wa"} } },
{"$match": {"_id": {"$ne": null }, "count": {"$gt": 1 } } }, 
{"$sort": {"count": -1 } }
])
```

credit to @turivishal comment. many thanks